# Mongoose: how to delete an array element by using its index

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, javascript-objects, mongoose-schema

This problem occurred to me and I was trying to find an answer online but unfortunately couldn't find one to satisfy my requirements.
In this case the problem which is solved for what I need, but I was thinking someone might look for same issue and find it hard to implemented, here I expose my solution in case you want to delete an array element using Mongoose, which this array element supposed to be an object.
I know I found a lot of information online about how can be delete using key and value pairs to match these object, but in my case I didn't want to delete them this way and I wanted to use the index method to delete these.

**Schema**

```
const JobSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

date: {
    type: Date,
    default: DateTime.local().toJSDate()
},
jobs: {
    type: []
},
updatedAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: DateTime.local().toJSDate()
}
```

})

**Data**

```js
const data = [{"_id": "606764002a7a5d49a82de976",
"date": "2020-03-05T00:00:00Z",
  "status": "worked",
  "jobs": [ // the array of objects elements needed to be modified
    {
      "for": "VOW",
      "paymentMethod": "time",
      "from": "12:00",
      "to": "20:00",
      "totalTime": "08:00",
      "rate": {
        "normal": 10,
        "overtime": 10
      },
      "payment": "102.85",
      "jobDetails": {
        "startedAt": "12:00",
        "endedAt": "20:00",
        "duration": "08:00"
      },
      "description": "worked for Anthony brought back van from Southport"
    },
    {
      "for": null,
      "paymentMethod": "general",
      "total": 102.34,
      "jobDetails": {
        "startedAt": "09:00",
        "endedAt": "12:00",
        "duration": "03:00"
      },
      "description": null
    },
    {
      "for": "Trueline",
      "paymentMethod": "mile",
      "rate": 1.5,
      "mileage": 100,
      "payment": 150,
      "jobDetails": {
        "startedAt": "20:00",
        "endedAt": "22:00",
        "duration": "02:00"
      },
      "description": null
    }
  ]
}]

console.log(data)
```

**My solution**

```
exports.deleteJob = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
try {

    // receive the date_id and the object position in the array you want to delete
    const { date_id, position } = req.body;

    // find the job by its id
    const job = await Mongoose
        .model('Job', JobSchema, 'name_of_your_mongo_collection')
        .findById(date_id)

    // set the specific field to null by capturing its position from client through 'position' variable
    job.jobs[position] = null

    // update with new data
    await Mongoose.model('Job', JobSchema, 'jobs_' + req.user._id).findByIdAndUpdate(date_id, job)

    // remove all null fields in the stated array
    await Mongoose
        .model('Job', JobSchema, 'jobs_' + req.user._id)
        .updateOne(
            { _id: date_id },
            { $pull: { jobs: null } }
        )

    // extract the job data again and send it to client
    const updatedJob = await Mongoose.model('Job', JobSchema, 'name_of_your_mongo_collection').findById(date_id);
    successResponse(updatedJob, 200, res);

} catch (error) {
    return errorHandler(error, res);
}});
```

> Note: this is not an unsolved problem for myself, as I had found the solution above and my code works as supposed, I thought it might help other people by using it or to find this information online to help them to adapt my solution to their unsolved problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a question. This should be posted on other mediums, like Medium, dev.to, etc.